# Django .filter only shows first object

Tags: django, django-filter

I am currently working in a database application in django. I want to add a advanced filter functionality to a page using django-filter, but I found an issue in my approach and I hope you could help me.

To illustrate my point,

```
Organism.objects.all().filter(lipids=Lipid.objects.all())
```

is only returning the Organism object that has the first Lipid object, instead of all the Organism objects....

More detail:
Let's say my models are:
Models:

```
class Organism(models.Model):
    species_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text="Species Name")
    strain_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text="Strain Name")
    lipids = models.ManyToManyField('Lipid',blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return('{}'.format(self.species_name))

class Lipid(models.Model):
    common_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    main_class = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return('{}'.format(self.common_name))
```

In the django-shell:

```
In [1]: from catalog.models import *
In [2]: o = Organism.objects.all()
In [3]: l = Lipid.objects.all()
In [4]: o
Out[4]: <QuerySet [<Organism: speceies_name_001>, <Organism: speceies_name_002>, <Organism: speceies_name_003>, <Organism: speceies_name_004>]>
In [5]: l
Out[5]: <QuerySet [<Lipid: common_name_001>, <Lipid: common_name_002>, <Lipid: common_name_003>, <Lipid: common_name_004>]>
In [6]: o.filter(lipids=l)

Out[6]: <QuerySet [<Organism: speceies_name_001>]>
```

I expect to see all the organisms in out[6], because I am not filtering anything!
I am sure this is a basic thing I am missing, but can't figure it out!

Comment: So you basically want all the organisms which have a lipid associated with them ?

Comment: Yes, actually this is a simplification of my problem, just to show my point. In this case I was expecting to see all the organisms, as I am filtering with all the lipids... and it is returning only the organism that has te fist lipid....I am sure it has to do with lipids being a manytomany field....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by doing following Django automatically selects first as relationship argument (smart one)

```
.filter(lipids=Lipid.objects.all())
```

what you wanted to achieve is following

```
.filter(lipids__in=Lipid.objects.all())
```

but better way would be to do following

```
.filter(lipids__isnull=False)
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! This solves the issue I asked, but unfortunately I tried to apply this to my real problem (combined with django-filters) and it keeps doing the same thing. I guess I will ask a new question with all the details.

Comment: New question.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42148018/django-filter-only-shows-first-object